# Map error: g.co/staticmaperror ( The request specifies more than 15 markers with a human readable address)

Tags: google-maps-static-api

I was using inside my app **Google Statics Maps API** to generate maps with 30 markers in average putting as input only zip codes.

Few weeks ago, My app started to crash because Google implemented a limit of 15 human readable addresses and zip codes are considered like that.

I know if I change my app to send Lat and Long, I will have only the limit of the URL size, but I want to know if using another kind of paid subscription this limit could be increased almost to 40.

My app was working very good but know my users are stopped because this change.

Thanks

Hector.

Comment: I believe you got an answer in the [public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10922)